# Populating field values for referred documents in aggregate call in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two base schemas ***User*** and ***Course***

//User Model

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please provide UserId.',
        index : true
    },
    Name :{
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim : true
    }
});
```

//Course Schema

```
var CourseSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill course title',
        trim: true,
        index: true
    },

    description: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'Category',
        index: true
    }
});
```

And a ***UserCourseProgress*** schema for storing each user's course progress.

```
var UserCourseProgress= new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: String,
        ref:'User',
        required: 'Please provide the User Id',
        index:true
    },
    courseid: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Course',
        required: 'Please provide the Course Id',
        index: true
    },
    timespent: {
        type: Number, //seconds
        default: 0
    },
    score: {
        type: Number 
    }
});
```

Now I have to aggregate results such over UserCourseProgress schema on Course level such that i show my result like this :
 - {Course Name}( {No_Of_Users_taken_Course} ) [e.g. Course A (15) ]

```
History.aggregate([{
        $group: {"_id": {"primary": "$courseid"},
        "popularityCount": {$sum: 1}}},
        {$sort:{"popularityCount":-1}},
        {$project:{"_id":0,
            "courseid":"$_id.primary",
            "count":1}}
    ])
```

Now want to **populate** Course title from Course Schema through its reference, but after going through the list of aggregation operators([here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)).I am not able to figure out a way to do so.

Can you suggest any way to populate data from other collections ??